# How do I stop .htaccess from stripping query string?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have an .htacces fil (for codeigniter) so that I don't need to include the index.php filename:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This works as intended:

http://domain.com/controller/method becomes http://domain.com/index.php/controller/method

However, this is not intended:

http://domain.com/controller/method/?option=yes becomes http://domain.com/index.php/controller/method

How would I keep the query string?

Comment: $config['enable_query_strings'] = true;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) (query string append) flag in your `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

From the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa):

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of `RewriteRule` is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.

Comment: Was not aware of this flag! Thanks!